# How can I switch input language with CapsLock on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, 18.04

How can I switch input language with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on Ubuntu 18.04? For some reason when I try to set <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as a switching key it enables Caps, but doesn't set it as switching language key.

When this window is open and I press <kbd>Caps</kbd>, the LED light switches on and off. But the key isn't registered.

[image: Set key combination for language switching]

**Update**: As explained in the linked post, you have to use Gnome Tweak Tool to change these settings.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Comment: If an answer to a linked duplicate question answers your question please vote for it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) I took the liberty to revert the change.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think it's helpful for visitors and reviewers to know that something worked for OP. If it can't be an answer (because of closure) then that information being somewhere makes more sense than it being nowhere, imho. (Also, in some cases the author of a duplicate question won't have the ability to upvote the target or its answers)

Comment: @Zanna: If you think so, I don't mind if you revert the changes. My voting advise was tailored specifically to PocketSam who has more than enough rep to vote.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks, I put it back, merging some of your improvements :)

Comment: @PocketSam: A small tip for program output and screenshots in future questions: you can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. With super-user privileges you need `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt ...` or `gksudo env LC_MESSAGES=POSIX synaptic` (for graphical applications).

Comment: I'd be curious if `gnome-tweak-tool` would have an option for that

Comment: `gnome-tweak-tool` has that option — but it doesn't work. See [my question](/questions/1123163/modeless-stateless-layout-language-switching-with-caps-lock-again-18-04-lts-bi) for a working solution!

Comment: yeah it's absolutely the best key to choose. thanks for posting this question.

Comment: After running the apt installation command the application can be found under the name "tweaks" having an icon with two switches.

Comment: Here is the solution that finally worked for me for Unbuntu 18.04 and 20.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123163/modeless-stateless-layout-language-switching-with-caps-lock-again-18-04-lts-bi